# Does PEG contain CFG?

Tags: fl.formal-languages, open-problem, grammars, context-free, parsing

> Despite their considerable expressive power, all [PEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar)s can be parsed in linear time using a tabular or memoizing parser (8). These properties strongly suggest that CFGs and PEGs define incomparable language classes, although a formal proof that there are context-free languages not expressible via PEGs appears surprisingly elusive.
>
> Bryan Ford, "[Parsing Expression Grammars: A Recognition-Based Syntactic Foundation](http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/lang/peg.pdf)", 2002.

Is there a context-free language that is not expressible as a PEG?

---

As pointed out by Emil, 
my proposed language $a^n a^* b^n$ does **not** work. 
It can be expressed as the PEG $S \to a S b / a S / \varepsilon$.

Comment: Ford also writes less ambiguously “it is not even proven yet that CFLs exist that cannot be recognized by a PEG”, so this would appear to be an open problem.

Comment: I didn't read the paper closely, but if I understand the definition correctly, your language is recognized by the PEG $S\to aSb/aS/\epsilon$.

Comment: You are right - that appears to recognize the language.

Comment: This is as far as I know an open problem.

Comment: By the way, the answer to the question is most probably that PEG does *not* contain CFG. PEGs can be recognized in linear time, but [as shown by Lee](http://theory.stanford.edu/~virgi/cs367/papers/leecfg.pdf): "a fast, practical CFG parser would yield a fast, practical BMM [Boolean matrix multiplication] algorithm, which is not believed to exist".